# how to check if a file is sorted on nth column in unix?

Tags: sorting, unix

lets say that I have a file as below:(comma separated)

```
cat test.csv
Rohit,India
Rahul,India
Surya Kumar,India
Shreyas Iyer,India
Ravindra Jadeja India
Rishabh Pant India
zzabc,abc
```

Now I want to check if the above file is sorted on 02nd column.
I tried the command sort -ct"," -k2,2 test.csv
I'm expecting it to say disorder in last line, but it is giving me disorder in 02nd line.
Could anybody tell me what is wrong here? and how to get the expected output?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The sort is not guaranteed to be stable.  But some implementations of `sort` support an option which will force that.  Try adding `-s`:

```
sort -sc -t, -k2,2 test.csv
```

but note that I would expect the first out of order line to be `Ravindra Jadeja India`, since the 2nd field of that line is the empty string which should sort before "India".

Comment: Thank you William for the answer. I learnt new thing to use with sort.
And regarding the lines "Ravindra Jadeja India" and "Rishabh Pant India" is mistake from me 
it should have been "Ravindra Jadeja, India" and "Rishabh Pant, India"

just one more question on this, suppose my file has 05 columns(same comma separated file) and I want to see if the file is sorted based on 03rd and 05th columns (not including 04th).
How can I do this?

Comment: lol! why would stability mater in this case ?

Comment: @Sorin Because a stable sort will not change the order of lines that have matching keys.  In this case, the problem occurs because of lines that have matching keys which are being re-ordered by the non-stable sort.